# Weird Issue while deploying Ghost container on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ghost-blog

**Spent a long time debugging the Issue**

I am trying to deploy a [Ghost](https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost) Docker Instance, backed by a MySQL db on GKE platform. [Here is the deployment and service kube](https://github.com/limosin/limosyn.com-configs) files for both. One by one I `kubectl apply -f <config.yml>` for each yml file in the following order:

1. `ssd-storageclass.yml` - create an ssd storage class.
2. `pvc-mysql.yml` - create a PVC Claim for MySQL.
3. `pvc-ghost.yml` - create a PVC Claim for ghost.
4. `deploy-mysql.yml` - create a MySQL deployment.
5. `service-mysql.yml` - expose MySQL instance.
6. `deploy-ghost.yml` - create ghost deployment.

Once done, I expose the ghost deployment via a Load balancer on Port `80` and get an `xx.xx.xx.xx` IP address for LB. I am able to access ghost on the generated IP address.

This is true as long as I have **env** variable `url` in `deploy-ghost.yml` set as "http://www.limosyn.com".

```yaml
[...]
      containers:
        env:
        [...]
        - name: database__connection__database
          value: mysql
        - name: url
          value: "http://www.limosyn.com"
[...]
```

Surprisingly, when I change the protocol from `http` to `https`, i.e. `https://www.limosyn.com`, I am no longer able to access the deployment on the LB assigned IP. The problem goes away on changing back to `http`.

I have tried tens of Permutations and combinations with and without `https`, doing clean deployments, etc. The situation remains the same. It never works with `https`.

Before I had the same infra deployed via docker-compose on a single vm instance with `https` baseurl and that worked. I am facing this issue with Kubernetes only.

You can easily reproduce the scenario if you have a cluster lying around.

Would really appreciate a resolution

Comment: Could you share your `LoadBalancer` configuration ?

Comment: I didn't apply any config for the LB as my ultimate goal is to route traffic using an ingress. But just to check if the app is working I was using the GKE dashboard to generate the LB. Nevertheless if you still need the LB config, I have created a file service-ghost-lb.yml file in the linked repository.

Comment: As to `service-ghost-lb.yml` you mentioned above, it's not `LoadBalancer`, it's simple `ClusterIP` service, which will expose your deployment only internally, within your cluster, making it available for other microservices. I was just wondering where exactly you _"change the protocol from http to https"_ ? Only in the URL you enter in the browser ? Or somewhere in your configuration ? Are you sure your application is able to terminate `https` connection ? If not, `LoadBalancer` provided by GCP won't be able to do it for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you create a kubernetes service of `LoadBalancer` type, 
Google Cloud controller configures a [network load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network) in your project. Note that it's not a proxy server of any kind. It simply forwards packets with no change to the source and destination IP addresses. That's all. If your application is not able to terminate https connection itself, using `https` protocol in such case obviously will not work. If this is the case, the correct approach is using GKE ingress right from the start.